# Laravel 5.2 - calculate expire date of my post

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

i would like that user can choice the expire of a post, for example in the form of create post i will insert a input select option with: 24h, 48h, 72h.

My question, i need store the date of expire in my database, how can i calculate it?

I know that i can get the time of creation post like this:

VIEW - MY form have a input like this

```
<select name="expire_date">
<option value="24">24h</option> 
<option value="48">48h</option>
<option value="72">72h</option>
</select>
```

MY CONTROLLER

```
 // get the current time  
    $current = Carbon::now();
    $current = new Carbon();
    // maybe so ?? 
    $expire_date = $current + $request->input('expire_date')
```

i would like create a variable with value of expire date post, i need store this data so i can show in my index list.

Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like that on your controller:
assuming you have Input::all() on your request variable.

```
$expire_date = Carbon::now()->addHours($request->expire_date);
```

as you can see on [carbon doc](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.strtotime.php) which can perform a calculation like this.

```
$expire_date = strtotime('+ '.$request->input('expire_date').' hours');
```

Another approach would be to add the seconds "manually":

```
$expire_date = time() + $request->input('expire_date') * 3600;
```

Answer (score 1):

The PHP DateTime class will do that quite happily like this

```
//example input parameter
$param = '24h';
// fix param, to upper case i.e. 24H
$param = strtoupper($param);

$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').PHP_EOL; 
$date->add(new DateInterval("PT$param"));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Result:

```
2016-10-17 19:58:56
2016-10-18 19:58:56
```